# Best way to create an interactive map using an existing image

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to create an interactive world map like in Europa Universalis IV or Crusader Kings II using Unity3D. These two games create the map using an existing image (like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAMr4.png). I have never done something like this before and I'm really confused on which is the best approach/technique to use.

What I need is an idea on how to show the map and be able to select every single province taken from the image.

Answer (score 0):

My method would require you to provide each region as an individual sprite.

---

1) Add all sprites to the scene and form the world map (`SpriteRenderer` or `UI.Image`).
2) Make a Component that handles interaction, and add it to each World Map Part `GameObject`.

- Implement the following interfaces to it, and specify the logic accordingly: [image]

3) Add the [Polygon Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html) Component to each World Map Part `GameObject`.
4) Add the [Physics Raycaster 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html) Component to your Camera.

---

If you choose to use `UI.Image` (which I do not recommend), you can skip steps 3 and 4, and instead set [alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold.html) to 1 on your World Map Part Component's `Awake()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That is similar to my initial idea, but it will require a lot of work since the provinces are hundreds. That's why I mentioned EU 4 and ck2. Is there a way to split the image using unity? Like loading the map as a Sprite and then splitting it into multiple subsprites

Comment: There is, but it's not really gonna work in your case, since you're gonna need to cut them up in square pieces, which can only be done from your 2d software. Making a game is very time consuming, and manually placing a hundred sprites into a scene should be a no-brainer. If you're still interested about splitting up a sprite, here's the relative link to the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html

Comment: What if i work with 3d models instead of sprites? Would it be possible?

Comment: In that case you'd have to have to add a lot of different colliders, assuming you want to go with one model.. You can do that with a 2D Sprite too, but again, it's not really recommended. Too limiting compared to what individual sprites could give you.